# Flutter Firebase Google Apple Facebook sign in

Tags: firebase, flutter, apple-sign-in

Lately my IOS app was rejected by Apple because I have only implemented Google and Facebook login and I am required to also provide Apple sign-in on IOS too.

For user with Facebook sign-in if the same email address used to login using Google/Apple previously, Firebase would require user to use the Google/Apple provider account to login subsequently.

I encountered this issue when the email address the user used to sign in are both Apple ID and also Facebook. On IOS, Firebase would require user to use Apple ID to sign in however at Android, subsequent sign in using Facebook were no longer allow as it was taken over by Apple sign in as the provider. The user unable to login Apple ID on Android, is there a way to get around it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue using authResult.user.linkWithCredential(credential).

final authResult = await _appleAuth(context); //get the Firebase AuthResult

if (authResult.user.email == email) {

await authResult.user.linkWithCredential(credential);

}

On Android prompt the user login Facebook on IOS first and link the credential since can't perform Apple Sign in on Android. I know my method is not smooth hopefully can perform Apple Sign In on Android using Flutter but not sure how to do it and could not find any info yet. At lease this is the get around. If anyone know easy way to perform Flutter Firebase Apple Sign in on Android, let me know.

[image]

Thanks to the link here for the idea: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1318